# JPA not generating ddl files

Tags: jpa

I'm setting up a JavaEE Webapplication and want to generate ddl files so I can see what they look like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             version="2.1">


        <persistence-unit name="contentAggregatorPU">
            <class>contentAggregator.model.Item</class>
            <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="contentAggregatorCreate.ddl"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="contentAggregatorDrop.ddl"/>
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

It just does not generate the files.

Comment: Works for me ...

Comment: i tried mvn clean install, build & deploy in two different wildfly application server and there is no .ddl file found on my entire harddrive :(

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I never used the mechanism. While it seems to work for my local-resource minimal JPA playground it gave me errors when attempting to deploy to wildfly. I've always used a small utility class for generating a schema.

```
public class SchemaTranslator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Class<?>[] entityClasses = { 
            Class1.class, 
            Class2.class,
        };

        MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySetting("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create")
            .applySetting("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect")
            // .applySetting("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "package.MyImprovedNamingStrategy")
            .build()
        );

        // [...] adding annotated classes to metadata here...
        for (Class<?> clazz : entityClasses)
            metadata.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);

        EnumSet<TargetType> targetTypes = EnumSet.of(TargetType.STDOUT, TargetType.SCRIPT);

        SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport()
            // .setHaltOnError( haltOnError )
            .setOutputFile("db-schema.sql")
            .setDelimiter(";");

        export.create(targetTypes, (MetadataImplementor) metadata.buildMetadata());

    }

}
```